# Duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml [ Ionic 3]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

Someone to help me with a problem with Ionic.

I want to add the Barcode Scan plugin to my project, but this is conflicting with the other Camera plugin, I've tried everything and it's not working ...

I tried to remove the line

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

in plugins/barcodescanner/plugin.xml, but gave the error 
"some input files use or override a deprecated api." 
Being that before built everything right.

Thanks

[That is my CMD log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT25t.png)

Comment: Manifest merger for android https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers